# Load Doc2Vec without the docs vectors only for infer_vector

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

I have big gensim Doc2vec model, I only need to infer vectors while i am loading the training documents vectors from other source.
Is it possible to load it as is without the big npy file

I did

**Edit:**

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
model_path = r'C:\model/model'
model = Doc2Vec.load(model_path)
model.delete_temporary_training_data(keep_doctags_vectors=False, keep_inference=True)
model.save(model_path)
```

remove the files `(model.trainables.syn1neg.npy,model.wv.vectors.npy)` **manually**

```
model = Doc2Vec.load(model_path)
```

but it ask for

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-7f868a7dbe0c>", line 1, in <module>
    model = Doc2Vec.load(model_path)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py", line 1113, in load
    return super(Doc2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 1244, in load
    model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 603, in load
    return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 427, in load
    obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 458, in _load_specials
    getattr(self, attrib)._load_specials(cfname, mmap, compress, subname)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 469, in _load_specials
    val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib), mmap_mode=mmap)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 428, in load
    fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\model/model.trainables.syn1neg.npy'
```

Note:
Those files not exists in the directory,
The model run on a server and download the model file from the storage
My question is, Do the model must have those files for inference?
I want to run it as low memory consumption as possible.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
Is the file model.trainables.syn1neg.npy is the model weights?
Is the file model.wv.vectors.npy is necessary for running an inference?

Comment: What do you mean by, "it ask for"? (Is there a specific error you could edit your question to show?)

Comment: @gojomo - Updated, Thanks

Comment: When did those errors appear – when running `.save()`, or later when running other code? Was there more info shown along with those errors, like a full error stack?

Comment: @gojomo - Sorry for the missing information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of the `delete_temporary_training_data()` method. It implies there's a clearer separation between training-state and that needed for later uses. (Inference is very similar to training, though it doesn't need the cached doc-vectors for training texts.)

That said, if you've used that method, you shouldn't then be deleting any of the side-files that were still part of the save. If they were written by `.save()`, they'll be expected, by name, by the `.load()`. They must be kept with the main model file. (There might be fewer such files, or smaller such files, after the `delete_temporary_training_data()` call - but any written must be kept for reading.)

The `syn1neg` file is absolutely required for inference: it's the model's hidden-to-output weights, needed to perform new forward-predictions (and thus also backpropagated inference-adjustments). The `wv.vectors` file is definitely needed in default `dm=1` mode, where word-vectors are part of the doc-vector calculation. (It might be optional in `dm=0` mode, but I'm not sure the code is armored against  them being absent - not via in-memory trimming, and definitely not against the expected file being deleted out-of-band.)

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I have deleted those file for check if the main model need them, I see that there is no benefit for delete_temporary_training_data.

Comment: Hand-deleting `model.docvecs` *might* leave inference working & save the most memory (if your training set was large) – so worth a try, if you don't need `most_similar()` results: `model.docvecs = None`

Comment: `model.infer_vector` still uses `model.docvecs.vector_size`, so instead of `model.docvecs = None` you may want to try `model.docvecs.vectors_docs_norm = None` and `model.docvecs.vectors_docs = None`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to load `gensim.Doc2Vec` without doc vectors for inference, I found this works:

```py
import gensim

fname = "path/to/model.pickle"
d2v = gensim.utils.unpickle(fname)
d2v.__recursive_saveloads = ["wv"] # Would normally be ['wv', 'dv']
d2v._load_specials(fname, None, *gensim.utils.SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname))
```

I know it's a pretty ugly hack, but in my case the doc vectors ended up being a 28GB file, and I didn't want to retrain.